# Get element data-attributes and insert them into the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ensure that when I click on the divs (A, B, C), the link of the button changes and gets the values of the data attributes in the appropriate places. I wrote a small script, but it does not work, and there is still not enough knowledge to understand exactly where I went wrong. Any help would be welcome.

```js
document.getElementById("product").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("purchase").href =
    "/?add-to-cart=" + this.data-product + 
    "&variation_id=" + this.data-id + "/";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product__items" id="product">

    <div data-id="338" data-product="A" id="uI-1" class="items-uniqueItem">A</div>
    <div data-id="339" data-product="B" id="uI-2" class="items-uniqueItem">B</div>
    <div data-id="340" data-product="C" id="uI-3" class="items-uniqueItem">C</div>

    <div class="product__items---btn">
        <a href="" id="purchase" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div><!-- btn -->

</div>
```

Comment: Sidenote: a `div` is not really great for click actions, try using a `button` instead. This will help accessibility since it can be focused and has the right semantics for screen readers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems here.

First, I suggest you consult the documentation for [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) or jQuery's [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Also, if you intend on using *event delegation*, you can't use `this` to refer to the event source element in a vanilla event listener as it will refer to the delegate.

Since you do have jQuery involved, you might as well use it since it makes this a lot easier (see also vanilla JS version below)

```js
const button = $("#purchase")

$("#product").on("click", ".items-uniqueItem[data-id][data-product]", function() {
  // Due to the selector above, `this` is now the clicked `<div>`
  
  // Extract data properties
  const { product, id } = $(this).data()
  
  // Construct URL parameters
  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    "add-to-cart": product,
    "variation_id": id
  })
  
  // Set the `href`
  button.prop("href", `/?${params}/`)
})
```

```css
/* this is just for visibility */
.items-uniqueItem{cursor:pointer;}#purchase{display:block;text-decoration:none;margin: 1rem;}#purchase:after{content:attr(href);display:block;color:#ccc;margin:.5rem;}
```

```html
<!-- your HTML, just minified -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="product__items" id="product"><div data-id="338" data-product="A" id="uI-1" class="items-uniqueItem">A</div><div data-id="339" data-product="B" id="uI-2" class="items-uniqueItem">B</div><div data-id="340" data-product="C" id="uI-3" class="items-uniqueItem">C</div><div class="product__items---btn"><a href="" id="purchase" class="btn">Button</a></div></div>
```

---

A vanilla JS version would look something more like this. You can use [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to locate the delegated event source

```js
const button = document.getElementById("purchase")

document.getElementById("product").addEventListener("click", e => {
  // find the required event source element
  const el = e.target.closest(".items-uniqueItem[data-id][data-product]")
  
  if (el) {
    // Extract data properties
    const { product, id } = el.dataset

    // Construct URL parameters
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
      "add-to-cart": product,
      "variation_id": id
    })

    // Set the `href`
    button.href = `/?${params}/`    
  }
})
```

```css
.items-uniqueItem{cursor:pointer;}#purchase{display:block;text-decoration:none;margin: 1rem;}#purchase:after{content:attr(href);display:block;color:#ccc;margin:.5rem;}
```

```html
<!-- your HTML, just minified -->
<div class="product__items" id="product"><div data-id="338" data-product="A" id="uI-1" class="items-uniqueItem">A</div><div data-id="339" data-product="B" id="uI-2" class="items-uniqueItem">B</div><div data-id="340" data-product="C" id="uI-3" class="items-uniqueItem">C</div><div class="product__items---btn"><a href="" id="purchase" class="btn">Button</a></div></div>
```

As you can see, it's not very different to the jQuery version so maybe [you might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: Thank you @Phil for your great solution. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. Maybe because I use <a></a> tag instead of a button?

Comment: @Morgari sorry, I don't understand your comment. You can clearly see it _working_ in the snippet above so what exactly doesn't work in your version? What happens instead? Do you get any errors reported in your console?

Comment: Thank you. I will explain in more detail what I mean. I have integrated your script, but unfortunately, nothing happens. The <a id="purchase" href="">Button</a> URL does not change when you click on the divs. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Thank you very much! Found a bug on my side and everything works just fine with your updated script!

Answer (score 2):

I've never personally used the `element.onlick = function() {...}` notation, so I'll be using`element.addEventListener('click', (e) => ...)`, but it should work the **same** **way**.

What you are doing is selecting the object that has the `id` "*product*". But "*product*" is the **parent** os the elements you want to select.

If you want to select **several** elements and do something with them, you can't use the `id` attribute, since `id` is unique for html page. So you'll want to use **classes** for that.

1. Create a `class` and add that class to each child (the ones with the `data-product`).
2. Select all children with `.querySelectorAll()`. Here is the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). This returns a **NodeList**, but it's similar to an Array.
3. Iterate thought the List with a `.forEach(item => ...)` where `item` represents each element of the list.
4. Add an **Event** Listener (or .click, I guess) on each item.

   ```js
   *theList*.forEach( (item) => {
     item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
       event.target.href = "/?add-to-cart=" + event.target.dataset.product + "&" + "variation_id=" + event.target.dataset.id + "/";
     })
   ));
   ```
5. To access a dataset in JS you use the `.dataset` property.

Comment: Just an FYI, OP doesn't want to update the `href` of the list items

Comment: @Phil You're right, didn't notice that. Anyway the logic is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, grab all the divs that have a given class so that we can use their data.

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.items-uniqueItem');
items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.target)))
```

Then inside you click handler you can get the button reference and assign the properties you want to get from it.